# Pure tones in Psychopy end with unwanted clicks

Tags: python, psychopy

Pure tones in Psychopy are ending with clicks. How can I remove these clicks?
Tones generated within psychopy and tones imported as .wav both have the same problem. I tried adding 0.025ms of fade out in the .wav tones that I generated using Audacity. But still while playing them in psychopy, they end with a click sound.

Now I am not sure how to go ahead with this. I need to perform a psychoacoustic experiment and it can not proceed with tone presentation like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicks in the beginning and end of sounds often occur because the sound is stopped mid-way so that the wave abruptly goes from some value to zero. This waveform can only be made using high-amplitude high-frequency waves superimposed on the signal, i.e. a click. So the solution is to make the wave stop while on zero.

Are you using an old version of psychopy? If yes, then upgrade. Newer versions add a Hamming window (fade in/out) to self-generated tones which should avoid the click.

For the .wav files, try adding (extra) silence in the end, e.g. 50 ms. It might be that psychopy stops the sound prematurely.

Comment: Well, in the compiler window, I added the hamming parameter as True and the problem seems to be solved. Sound is definitely smoother. But then I am assuming I'll have to make my experiment in the compiler view and not in the builder view. Because there are 8 sound stimuli which I would have imported via builder view through an xlsx file. But hamming can only be applied to tones generated within Psychopy. Right?   I am new to Psychopy and hence asking this. Thanks.

Comment: You can always make the desired change in the code as a last step before running your experiment. It's not optimal but at least it's a solution. Yes, hamming window applies to tones generated within psychopy.

Comment: I still do not understand why the Hamming window improves anything. You already *did* have an onset/offset ramp in your wave files; and for the pure tones generated by PsychoPy, the window is applied automatically.

Comment: Oh I should have been more precise. I am not sure as to why is this occurring but the wave files that I am importing into psychopy when played during the experiment, end with a pop/click independent of whether I had applied the onset / offset ramp or not. Yes, wave files with the ramp have reduced click sounds and also less frequent but yet they are there. But interestingly, sounds generated within Psychopy do not have the same problem.Yes, you are right. As it turns out, hamming is applied by default in Psychopy.
Now I'll have to code in psychopy which is not as convenient as importing sounds

Comment: Problem Soved !!
@JonasLindeløv I totally forgot to test the last part you mentioned: Adding 50ms silence to the wave files. 

So basically adding a 25ms onset/offset ramp and adding silence of 50ms in the end has given me the perfect sound stimuli without any clicks/pops. Thanks all !!

Comment: Very interesting. This could be pointing to a problem within PsychoPy itself, or in the audio libraries it uses.

Answer (score 2):

Crackling sounds or clicks are, to my knowledge, often associated with buffering errors. Many years back, I experienced similar problems on Linux systems when an incorrect bitrate was set. So there could be at least two possible culprits at work here: the bitrate, and the buffer size.

You already applied both an onset and offset ramp to allow the membranes to swing in/out, so this should not be the issue. (By the way, I think you meant 0.025 *seconds* instead of ms? Otherwise, the ramps would be too short!)

PyGame [initializes](https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/blob/master/psychopy/sound.py#L499) the sound system with the following settings:

```
initPygame(rate=22050, bits=16, stereo=True, buffer=1024)
```

Whereas Pyo [initializes](https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/blob/master/psychopy/sound.py#L548) it the following way:

```
initPyo(rate=44100, stereo=True, buffer=128)
```

The documentation of `psychopy.sound` states:

> For control of bitrate and buffer size you can call psychopy.sound.init before
>   creating your first Sound object:
>
> ```
> from psychopy import sound
> sound.init(rate=44100, stereo=True, buffer=128)
> s1 = sound.Sound('ding.wav')
> ```

So, I would suggest you:

- Try out both sound backends, Pyo and PyGame -- you can change which one to use in the PsychoPy preferences under *General / audio library*. Change the field to `['pyo']` to use Pyo only, or to `['pygame']` to use only PyGame.
- Experiment with different settings for bitrate and buffer size with both backends (Pyo, PyGame).

If you want to get started with serious psychoacoustics, however, I would suggest you do not use either of the proposed solutions, and get some piece of professional sound hardware or a data-acquisition board with analog outputs, which will deliver undistorted sound with sub-millisecond precision, such as the devices produced by National Instruments or competitors. The NI boards can be controlled from Python via [PyLibNIDAQmx](https://github.com/pearu/pylibnidaqmx/).

Comment: Sorry, I meant 25ms. I tried playing around with the backends and their parameters. There seems to be change in the clicks but the pattern is too random. There is not a certain parameter value at which I can totally negate them. I am obviously playing around with buffer only. The rest I want to be at 44100 and 32 bit anyway.
Although I just tried adding 50ms of silence to the already edited (onset/offset ramp) files and I now seem to have near perfect rendering. Perhaps I'll go ahead with this.